# JS array of literals to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

In JS, I have the following:

```
var languages = [{
    language: "da"
    listening: "A1"
}, {
    language: "en"
    listening: "B2"
}];
```

What I end up with, in PHP, after an `$.ajax` call is:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["language"]=>
    string(2) "da"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["listening"]=>
    string(2) "A1"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["language"]=>
    string(0) "en"
  }
  ...
}
```

What I need is something like this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["language"]=>
    string(2) "da",
    ["listening"]=>
    string(2) "A1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["language"]=>
    string(2) "en",
    ["listening"]=>
    string(2) "B1"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this in a simple? Do I have to iterate and process it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean something like this:

```
var languages = [{
    language: "da"
    listening: "A1"
}, {
    language: "en"
    listening: "B2"
}];
```

So you actually have two objects to transfer to PHP, packed into an array, right?. Try using JSON:

Create a JSON string and send it to the server:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '...',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { json: JSON.stringify(languages)}
});
```

On server side you'll now have the json string in $_POST['json'] and you can decode it with:

```
json_decode($_POST['json'], true);
```

to get a (multidimensional) array, or

```
json_decode($_POST['json']);
```

for an array containing two objects.

**EDIT**

If you have "Magic Quotes" on, you'll have to strip the backslashes first:

```
json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['json']), true);
```

HTH,

Comment: I pasted from the JS console, you are right: an array of objects.

Comment: Christian David, I receive an escaped `JSON string` but after running `json_decode`, a `var_dump` outputs `NULL`.

Comment: Hi, can you check if there was an error? You can use www.php.net/json_last_error for that if you have PHP 5.3. And please dump the json string from $_POST['json'], perhaps there are some special chars, e.g. slashes that are quoted?

Comment: Ah, so try json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['json']), true), this should remove the "\" and result in a valid json string. Edit: check this to understand where these backslashes come from: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php

Comment: !this worked! now I have an `array(array("language"=>string(2)..."da",array(),...)`

Answer (score 3):

Use `JSON.stringify` to encode your data structure, send the resulting string as a single param, then decode it with `json_decode($json, true)` in PHP.

**JS**

```
var data = [
   { language: "da", listening: "A1"}, 
   { language: "en", listening: "B2"}
];
// ...
$.post(url, { data: JSON.stringify(data) }, function() { ... });
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
  $data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
  // process this array of arrays
}
```

Comment: raina77ow, `json_decode` expects a string as the first param, it seems that the `$_POST['data']` gets as `array`.

Comment: @jima: surprised that it does come out as an array... instead of jibberish. 
Raina77ow, you forgot to JSON.stringify your data variable when you stick into the request

Comment: @user1600124 You're right, JSON.stringify should be used here; without it, array of objects (as encoded by [$.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)) will be sent instead.

Comment: @jima Check the updated code, it's weird that I didn't follow my own advice, somehow thinking that jQuery will serialize the data anyway. ) It does, true, but using its own method - $.param - not `JSON.stringify`, that's why you get array in return, not a string.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, check the right answer, i had to use the `json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['json']), true); `

Answer (score 0):

Hello:

I think you should try out as follows javascript

```
{
    "languages": [
        {"language":"da","listening":"A1"},
        {"language":"en", "listening":"B2"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: If you give this text output, and comes in json format, remember that in the end Json is a well-formed string for Javascript Object Notation in the encoding you're using, you do not need to do the encode in php already, and if you want to use ajax and you know you will get a json output, I recommend to use the method $. json

Comment: It is more a problem of interpreting `it` in PHP. I send `stuff` from JS through `ajax`. The concern is how to make sense of what I receive on the server. So if I send JS objects, PHP "scrambles" them. If I send a JSON and then decode in PHP, I get the equivalent of JS, but in PHP. I think your solution will not solve it because it contains JS objects/arrays NOT JSON (string).